# How to write an interface that is automatically extended based on a component prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Say I have a `Button` component. It has a corresponding `ButtonProps` interface.

```
interface ButtonProps {
  component?: ComponentType;
  label: ReactNode;
  onClick?: (evt: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
}
```

How does one write `ButtonProps` in such a way that it is automatically built to accept all the props that are taken by whatever is passed as the `component` prop? For example,

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Button
  component={Link}
  label="Home"
  to="/home"
/>
```

In the above snippet, I'd like for `Button` to be typed in such a way that it understands and accepts the `to` prop because it is a prop defined on `Link` which is passed as the `component` prop.

Answer (score 0):

It's my first approach to your problem is as follows but you'd have to modify the props that inherit the button props... Maybe I can help you come up with a solution:

**Link.js**

```
interface LinkProps {
  label: React.ReactNode;
  to: string;
}

const Link: React.FC<LinkProps> = ({label, to}) => 
  <React.Fragment>
    <a href={to}>{label}</a>
  </React.Fragment>;
```

**Button.js**

```
type ButtonProps<T extends {}> = T & {
  Component?: React.ComponentType<T>;
  onClick?: (evt: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
};

const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps<LinkProps>> = ({Component , ...rest}) => 
  <button>
    <Component {...rest} />
  </button>
```

I attach [the link where I was doing the tests](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ea2rfq)

Answer (score -1):

Try out the following code:

```
<Button
    component={Link}
    {...{
        label: "Home"
        to: "/home"
    }}
/>
```

Anything you pass in the {...{  }} will be passed as props to the Link. In case you have a custom component, make sure you pass them in.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. `ButtonProps` still doesn't understand and correctly type the `to` prop, for example.